# showing simple inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

How can I prove this simple equality?

$\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\leq0.5$

I know that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq1$. But I don't how to use this  in order to show the assertion. I also know that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is always smaller than one. So when I'm dividing this by $x$ I get $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+x}...$(again I don't know how to go on)

Comment: when $x=0$ it is obvious. Assume $x \neq 0$. Then $1+x^2 \geq 2|x|$ by AM-GM inequality.

Comment: WLOG $x=\tan y$

Comment: false for $x = 1$

Comment: $1 + x^2 \ge 2|x|$ by AM-GM but also $(1 - |x|)^2 \ge 0$ so $1 -2|x|  + x^2 \ge 0$ so $1 + x^2 \ge 2|x|$ and so $\frac 12 \ge \frac {|x|}{1 + x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \ne 1$
$$ (x-1)^2 = x^2-2x+1 \gt 0$$
and then
$$ 2x \lt 1+x^2$$

Comment: false for $x=1$

Answer (score 1):

Since the LHS is always positive, we can simply rearrange and form a quadratic in $|x|$:

$$x^2 - 2|x| + 1  > 0\\
 (|x| -1)^2 > 0$$

which is true for all $x $ except $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For real $x, x^2=|x|^2$

Now let $$y=\dfrac{|x|}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{|x|}{|x|^2+1}$$

$$\iff y|x|^2-|x|+y=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $|x|$

As $|x|$ is real, the discriminant $(-1)^2-4y^2\ge0\iff-\dfrac12\le y\le\dfrac12$

But $y=\dfrac{|x|}{x^2+1}\ge0$ for real $x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac {|x|}{1 + x^2} < .5 \iff$

$2|x| < 1 + x^2 \iff$

$0 < 1 - 2|x| + x^2 \iff$

$0 < (1 - |x|)^2 \iff$

$1 -|x| \ne 0 \iff$

$|x| \ne 1\iff$

$x \ne 1$ or $x \ne -1$.

So the statement as you wrote it is not true.  But it is true for all $x: |x| \ne 1$.

And $\frac {|x|}{1+ x^2} \le .05$ with equality holding if and only  if $|x| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

What if $x=0?$

For real $x,x^2=|x|^2$ $$\dfrac{|x|}{1+x^2}=\dfrac1{|x|+\dfrac1{|x|}}$$

$$\dfrac{|x|+\dfrac1{|x|}}2\ge\sqrt{|x|\cdot\dfrac1{|x|}}$$